# How to use Bootstrap.css in some modules in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-module

Is it possible to use **`bootstrap.css`** in some modules instead of the whole application?

I do not want to add Bootstrap.css to index.html or to styles of `angular.json`, just in some modules.

In my project, there are two sections (**Admin/Client**). I would like to use `Bootstrap` in **Client section** and use `Material` in **Admin section**.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use bootstrap in some modules just import in your css file, like as

```
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Component inheritance.

```
1. Client Base

@Component({
    selector: 'client-base',
    templateUrl: './client-base.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./client-base.component.scss', 'bootstrap.css']
})

export class ClientBaseComponent {}

///

2. Client Component be like

@Component({
    selector: 'client-component',
    templateUrl: './client-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./client-component.component.scss']
})

export class ClientComponent extends ClientBaseComponent  {}

////

3. Admin Base

@Component({
    selector: 'admin-base',
    templateUrl: './admin-base.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./admin-base.component.scss', 'Material.css']
})

export class AdminBaseComponent {}

///

2. Admin Component be like

@Component({
    selector: 'admin-component',
    templateUrl: './admin-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./admin-component.component.scss']
})

export class AdminComponent extends AdminBaseComponent {}
```